# Undocking a control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I can currently dock a child control using the following line quite easily:

```
DockPanel.SetDock(group, Dock.Top);
```

(or any of the other three choices)

The problem I have is this: I'm trying to provide an accordion style menu where the collapsed items appear above or beneath the currently selected menu.

But how do I undock an item so that it fills the available space within the dockpanel once it has previously been docked to one side? The SetDock() method doesn't appear to allow this. I don't want to remove the item entirely just get it to fill the available space from within a function.

Comment: Have a look at the `Grid` element. The `DockPanel` can be seen as a particular case of the `Grid`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-grid-element?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the attached property value. Something like this:

```
group.ClearValue(DockPanel.DockProperty);
```